# Creating a column based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested

I'm a longtime SAS user trying to get into Pandas. I'd like to set a column's value based on a variety of if conditions. I think I can do it using nested np.where commands but thought I'd check if there's a more elegant solution. For instance, if I set a left bound and right bound, and want to return a column of string values for if x is left, middle, or right of these boundaries, what is the best way to do it? Basically if x < lbound return "left", else if lbound < x < rbound return "middle", else if x > rbound return "right".

```
df
   lbound   rbound  x
0   -1      1       0
1   5       7       1
2   0       1       2
```

Can check for one condition by using np.where:

```
df['area'] = np.where(df['x']>df['rbound'],'right','somewhere else')
```

But not sure what to do it I want to check multiple if-else ifs in a single line.

Output should be:

```
df
   lbound   rbound  x    area
0   -1      1       0    middle
1   5       7       1    left
2   0       1       2    right
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use nested `np.where` statements. For example:

```
df['area'] = np.where(df['x'] > df['rbound'], 'right', 
                      np.where(df['x'] < df['lbound'],
                               'left', 'somewhere else'))
```

**Option 2**

You can use `.loc` accessor to assign specific ranges. Note you will have to add the new column before use. We take this opportunity to set the default, which may be overwritten later.

```
df['area'] = 'somewhere else'
df.loc[df['x'] > df['rbound'], 'area'] = 'right'
df.loc[df['x'] < df['lbound'], 'area'] = 'left'
```

**Explanation**

These are both valid alternatives with comparable performance. The calculations are vectorised in both instances. My preference is for Option 2 as it seems more readable. If there are a large number of nested criteria, `np.where` may be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy select instead of np.where

```
cond = [df['x'].between(df['lbound'], df['rbound']), (df['x'] < df['lbound']) , df['x'] > df['rbound'] ]
output = [ 'middle', 'left', 'right']

df['area'] = np.select(cond, output, default=np.nan)



    lbound  rbound  x   area
0   -1      1       0   middle
1   5       7       1   left
2   0       1       2   right
```